# SSMS unable to create query

Tags: ssms, ssms-2016

I tried to install the SSMS using the basic version for the developer, After successful installation of the SSMS and studios. I am able to connect to the sql db server but unable to create new query. When i try i get the following error,

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.Tracing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. (System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow)

I understand this is the issue with the configuration. I am unable to solve it. Can anyone help me with this?

1. Tried repairing
2. Uninstall and reinstall
3. Tried to install .net in the VScode also.
4. Tried install the previous version.
5. server is pingable and I am able to use it from other's system also.

Comment: Have you tried using the latest version of SSMS? SSMS 16 is far from recent. The latest release is SSMS 19.3.